# How can I remember whether finite or countable cartesian product of countable set is countable

Tags: soft-question, cardinals, mnemonic

I always forget this result

> Is cartesian product of countable set countable under finite or
>   countable cartesian products?

Is there a good way to remember this? Like a proof sketch where the proof would go wrong if we take the product of too many countable sets?

Comment: It should be countable under finite products. When you observe a countable cartesian product of countable sets, for example $\mathbb{N}$, you can think about the result as infinite decimal number. And the real numbers are uncountable. That the finite cartesian product of countable sets, is countable, is "clear".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose each of your countable sets actually is $\mathbb{N}$. Then a countable product of them would have elements of the form

$$(n_0,n_1,\dots)$$

i.e. an infinite sequence of natural numbers.

Any real number in $[0,1]$ has a decimal expansion of the form

$$0.d_0d_1\dots$$

i.e. an infinite sequence of digits in $\{0,\dots,9\}$.

Since $\{0,\dots,9\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, there are at least as many sequences of natural numbers as there are reals in $[0,1]$, i.e. uncountably many.